# find and replace macro in libreoffice

Tags: find, replace, libreoffice, macro

How can I write a find and replace macro to merge many items in few, as "USA, Mexico, Canada, Honduras" in "America", "China, India, Vietnam" in "Asia" and so.
 
Before macro: USA, Mexico, Canada, Honduras 
After macro: America, America, America, America

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookup function in Calc to do this.

Documentation here: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_LOOKUP_function

you need your data in columns for this to work, then you would do something like:

```
LOOKUP(3; A1:E1; A3:E3)
```

for each row in the data.

Comment: sorry, I need a librewriter macro; thank you

Comment: This was for me the solution: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/129141/find-and-replace-macro/.